# Python typing class type in single quotes

Tags: python, oop, typing

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, ......  

    def make_friend(self, friend: 'Person') -> None:
        .....
```

I'm learning python and I don't understand this example. Why type condition for friend should be in single quotes? Why not `friend: Person`? How it can works? Does it have something common with type class shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `make_friend` is defined before the class `Person`.

When classes are made, first the namespace (internal class functions) is created, and then it is built into the class (using the `__prepare__` method).

Trying to reference `Person` before it is created will fail.

Solving it can be done with a "forward reference", which can be used with quotes or with a `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file.